# rustlings move_semantics2 why passing reference doest not work?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

i am trying Rust by doing the restlings exercices that is a very good approach to start with but there is something that i do not understand.

### Exercice: move_semantics2

I understand that in order to initialize vec1 with the content of vec0 without taking the ownership away we have to either clone vec0 or to pass by reference. The issue is that this code, that passes references doesn't seem to work.

I wanna understand why, any idea ?

```rust
// move_semantics2.rs
// Make me compile without changing line 13 or moving line 10!
// Execute `rustlings hint move_semantics2` or use the `hint` watch subcommand for a hint.

// I AM NOT DONE

fn main() {
    let vec0 = Vec::new();

    let mut vec1 = fill_vec(&vec0);

    // Do not change the following line!
    println!("{} has length {} content `{:?}`", "vec0", vec0.len(), vec0);

    vec1.push(88);

    println!("{} has length {} content `{:?}`", "vec1", vec1.len(), vec1);
}

fn fill_vec(vec: &Vec<i32>) -> &Vec<i32> {
    let mut vec = vec;

    vec.push(22);
    vec.push(44);
    vec.push(66);

    vec
}
```

this is the error i am getting :

```rust
⚠️  Compiling of exercises/move_semantics/move_semantics2.rs failed! Please try again. Here's the output:
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
 --> exercises/move_semantics/move_semantics2.rs:8:9
  |
8 |     let mut vec1 = fill_vec(&vec0);
  |         ----^^^^
  |         |
  |         help: remove this `mut`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*vec1` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> exercises/move_semantics/move_semantics2.rs:13:5
   |
8  |     let mut vec1 = fill_vec(&vec0);
   |         -------- consider changing this binding's type to be: `&mut Vec<i32>`
...
13 |     vec1.push(88);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `vec1` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> exercises/move_semantics/move_semantics2.rs:19:9
   |
19 |     let mut vec = vec;
   |         ----^^^
   |         |
   |         help: remove this `mut`

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*vec` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> exercises/move_semantics/move_semantics2.rs:21:5
   |
19 |     let mut vec = vec;
   |         ------- consider changing this binding's type to be: `&mut Vec<i32>`
20 |
21 |     vec.push(22);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `vec` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*vec` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> exercises/move_semantics/move_semantics2.rs:22:5
   |
19 |     let mut vec = vec;
   |         ------- consider changing this binding's type to be: `&mut Vec<i32>`
...
22 |     vec.push(44);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `vec` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*vec` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> exercises/move_semantics/move_semantics2.rs:23:5
   |
19 |     let mut vec = vec;
   |         ------- consider changing this binding's type to be: `&mut Vec<i32>`
...
23 |     vec.push(66);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `vec` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable

error: aborting due to 4 previous errors; 2 warnings emitted

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
```

Comment: You cannot magically fabricate a mutable reference from an immutable one simply by writing `let mut vec = vec;`. You should declare `fill_vec` to take and return a ` &mut Vec` and pass it a `&mut vec0`

Comment: @user2407038 then it wouldn't compile cause `vec0` can't be accessed while it's borrowed.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" what's the error you're getting?

Comment: post has been updated with the error, @user2407038 this is what i did for the move_semantics3 but i still don't get why this version did not work.

Comment: What exactly is `fill_vec` supposed to do? What is the expected output of the two `println`s?

Comment: it is just an exercice to familiarize with ownership in Rust, the function is supposed to "clone" then add items in the vector withtout throwing away the ownership of vec0, the println are just here to test if the ownership is still present, at least this is my guess

Comment: I'm not familiar with this exercise so I cannot say how this should be fixed. I would be wary of trying to learn any language by trying to satisfy arbitrary "make this compile" constraints. It's rare to write programs this way in the real world, in particular, because there are no constraints that I can see about what this program must **do**, only that it must compile. The simplest change would be to change `fn fill_vec(vec: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> { let mut vec = vec.clone(); < same as before >`, but I could also write `fn fill_vec(vec: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> { Vec::new() }`

Comment: Incidentally, there is no "passing by reference" in Rust. Everything is passed by value. In your case, your just passing a reference by value, which is not the same as passing by reference.

Comment: okay, i get it now, this is the way i wanted to do it but i was trynna initialize a variable intead of changing directly the reference, thank you for your answers: fn main() {
    let mut vec0 = Vec::new();

    let mut vec1 = fill_vec(&mut vec0);

    println!("{} has length {} content `{:?}`", "vec1", vec1.len(), vec1);

    vec1.push(88);

    println!("{} has length {} content `{:?}`", "vec1", vec1.len(), vec1);
}

fn fill_vec(vec: &mut Vec<i32>) -> &mut Vec<i32> {
    vec.push(22);
    vec.push(44);
    vec.push(66);

    vec
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your misconception stems from this line in `fill_vec()`:

```rust
let mut vec = vec;
```

That line is not making a copy of the original vector, instead it tries to make the original immutable reference to the passed in vector mutable, which naturally the compiler does not allow. If your intent was to make a copy of the the passed-in vector, you would want your function to look like this:

```rust
fn fill_vec(vec: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut new_vec = vec.clone();

    new_vec.push(22);
    new_vec.push(44);
    new_vec.push(66);

    new_vec
}
```

Note that this new version uses `clone()` to copy the original vector, and instead of returning a reference to a vector, it returns a new vector.

Answer (score 0):

Because this question's expectation is below:

```rust
// Expected output:
// vec0 has length 3 content `[22, 44, 66]`
// vec1 has length 4 content `[22, 44, 66, 88]`
```

So I think below is a better solution.

```rust
let vec0 = Vec::new();

let vec0 = fill_vec(vec0);

// Do not move the following line!
let mut vec1 = vec0.clone();
```